# Finding a file with a unique prefix in O(1) time in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, file-handling

In an iPad application, I have a folder with the following files:

```
1-1-xxxx.dat
1-2-xxxx.dat
...
1-999-xxxx.dat
2-1-xxxx.dat
...
...
999-999-xxxx.dat
```

Where the `xxxx` parts are characters determined at run-time when the files are created. The contents of each file depends on the contents of the previous one, and so with each file I create, I need to query the previous file. The problem is, I only know the prefix of the previous file and not the `xxxx` part, as the 'xxxx' part is essentially random. (The `xxxx` part is itself determined by the `xxxx` part of the previous file, with the `1-1-xxxx` file being randomly named).

To get access to the file, an initial approach would be:

```
// For file 1-50-xxxx.dat
NSError *error = nil;
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *allFiles = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];

for (NSString *file in allFiles) {
    if ([file hasPrefix:@"1-49-"]) {
        // Determine contents and name of file "1-50-xxxx.dat"
        // Create file, break, etc.
    }
}
// ... And repeat for many files
```

This obviously becomes very expensive very quickly. Is there an O(1) way of getting the path of the required file as there will only ever be a single file with a given numeric prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you build a dictionnary of the names and then lookup in that dictionnary the path? The dictionnary keys would be the prefix and the values the full path.

i.e.: (pseudo-code)

```
// Build the path dictionnary, that is done only once
currentPrefix = ...
previousXXX   = null
foreach file
  currentXXX = computeXXX( previousXXX )
  dictionnary.put( currentPrefix, computePath( currentPrefix, currentXXX )

  // Remember for next iteration
  previousXXX = currentXXX 
  currentPrefix++
endforeach
```

Then, knowing a prefix, getting the path is easy and fast (how fast depends on the dictionnary implementation used of course): dictionnary.get( prefix )

---

To build the content of your files, just apply the same logic: on each iteration, remember the previous file's content / suffix and use that instead of computing it again from the start.